# Django email backend ssl

Tags: python, django, ssl

I really need your help! When I try to send an email I get a strange error.

Backend (django 1.6.5):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = "mail.example.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "example_mail@mail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "example_pass"
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/User/.virtualenvs/rshu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 50, in send_mail
    connection=connection).send()
  File "/Users/User/.virtualenvs/rshu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 274, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/Users/User/.virtualenvs/rshu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 87, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/Users/User/.virtualenvs/rshu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_smtp_ssl.py", line 14, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 615, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure')
```

Maybe someone else has already solved this problem?

```
send_mail('test email', 'hello', '', ['example@gmail.com'])
connect: ('mail.example.com', 465)
connect: ('mail.example.com', 465)
reply: '220 relay.example.com ESMTP Postfix\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: relay.example.com ESMTP Postfix
connect: relay.example.com ESMTP Postfix
send: 'ehlo maxs-mbp-2.dlink\r\n'
reply: '250-relay.example.com\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 104857600\r\n'
reply: '250-ETRN\r\n'
reply: '250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5\r\n'
reply: '250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250 DSN\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: relay.example.com
PIPELINING
SIZE 104857600
ETRN
AUTH LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
8BITMIME
DSN
send: 'AUTH CRAM-MD5\r\n'
reply: '334 PDM3NDg0NzcwODMuNDc5ODUzNEByZWxheS5yc2h1LnJ1Pg==\r\n'
reply: retcode (334); Msg: PDM3NDg0NzcwODMuNDc5ODUzNEByZWxheS5yc2h1LnJ1Pg==
send: '...\r\n'
reply: '535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure\r\n'
reply: retcode (535); Msg: 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/User/.virtualenvs/rshu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 50, in send_mail
    connection=connection).send()
  File "/Users/User/.virtualenvs/rshu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 274, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/Users/User/.virtualenvs/rshu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 87, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/Users/User/.virtualenvs/rshu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_smtp_ssl.py", line 14, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 615, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure')
>>>
```

new backend:

```
class SSLEmailBackend(EmailBackend):
    def open(self):
        if self.connection:
            return False
        try:
            self.connection = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(
                self.host, self.port, local_hostname=DNS_NAME.get_fqdn())

            if self.username and self.password:
                self.connection.ehlo()
                # Remove CRAM-MD5 authentication method
                self.connection.esmtp_features['auth'] = 'PLAIN LOGIN'
                self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
            return True
        except:
            if not self.fail_silently:
                raise
```

Comment: That's no ssl problem. The error message comes from your SMTP server. Double check if user and password are correct, and if sending mails from other email clients works.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had already checked it several times =(

Comment: Then please check/append (with the password removed, of course) the debug output of smtplib to your post. You can enable it globally by calling `import smtplib; smtplib.SMTP.debuglevel = 1` before you try to send a mail. The output will be written to `stderr`, i.e. to your console if you use Django's `runserver`.

Comment: The traceback in console doesn't show me anything new

Comment: It does show you that Python attempts to do a cram-md5 authentication, which the email client you've used for testing probably didn't. Your server seems to be misconfigured. Either contact its admin and ask him to fix cram-md5 (or disable it), or replace the `smtplib` module with a custom copy with cram-md5 disabled. (Line 581 in smtplib.py in Python 2.7)

Comment: I added a new ssl backend (added to the bottom of the post) and got rid of the error.Now I have another one SMTPRecipientsRefused: {u'destination@gmail.com': (553, '5.7.1 <webmaster@localhost>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user sender@test.com')}